# #include "colour.h" fatal error in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to code something similar to Conway's game of life. Everything seems fine but I having a fatal error with #include "colour.h". The code is in c++ and i know this API belongs to C. I dont know that if it is going to make a difference or I have to use another API for C++. The reason is on my desktop computer I dont have to change anything and program runs perfect. But When I run the program on my other computer it gives the fatal error with the first line of the code(#include "colour.h"). I dont know why It gives error.

See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)

```
 #include "colours.h"
 #include <sstream>   //
 #include <iomanip>   // setw()
 #include <windows.h> // setConsoleTitle(), Sleep()
 #include <cstdlib>   // rand(), seed()
 #include <iostream>  // cout

 using namespace std;

 // OUR DATA and CONSTANTS
 const char LIFE  = 'L';
 const char BLANK = '.';

 const int N = 20;
 const int M = 20;
 const int NGRID = N*M;
 char world[NGRID];    // will simulate 2-dimenisonal array.

 int loc(int i, int j)
 {
   return i*M+j*sizeof(char);
 }

 void gotoxy(int x, int y, char c)
 {
  world[ loc(x,y)] = c;
 }

   // OUR FUNCTIONS (ie, TOOLS) that work on our DATA
  void fillWorldwith(char w[], const int N, const int M, const char stuff){
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
  w[loc(i,j)]=stuff;
 }

 void displayWorld(char *w, const int N, const int M){
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
 {
  for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
  cout << setw(2) << w[loc(i,j)];
  cout << endl;
 }
 }

  // Used in applyRules as a buffer to update world.
  void copyWorld(char dest[], char src[], const int N, const int M){

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
     for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
      dest[loc(i,j)]= src[loc(i,j)];
  }


int main()
{
  SMALL_RECT windowSize;                              // windows
  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // windows

  windowSize = {0, 0, 200, 200};
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &windowSize); // windows
  SetConsoleTitle("Game of Life");                   // windows

  system("cls");               // clear the console

  stringstream ss;  // trick to combine string and numbers
  ss << "color " << Black << Yellow;

  // objects are fun to use.
  system( ss.str().c_str() );   // change console colour

  fillWorldwith(world, N, M, BLANK);     // fill whole world with BLANKS
  displayWorld(world, N, M);
  int x=0, y =0;
   for(int time=0; time<100; time++){  // each loop, considered time.
   system("cls");
   displayWorld(world, N, M);              // display world
   gotoxy(x, y, BLANK);
   x= (x+1)%N;
   y= (y+1)%M;
   gotoxy(x, y, LIFE);
   Sleep(50);

  }

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Show the "colours.h" file. This might be useful

Comment: As I wrote the first line of the code gives a fatal error. It additionally says that no such file or directory.

Comment: It cannot find the file, see answer below.

Comment: Please fix your question: the text and title use `colour.h` but the code uses `colours.h`. And check the British spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colours.h` isn't a standard include file, so the problem is that it isn't available on the other machine. You need to install the software that provides it (or copy it there if it is a file you have created yourself).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the default include directories for your compiler correctly or place the `colours.h` file in the same directory as your other files.